# drupal ajax changes my fieldset to a copy of the incorrect fieldset

Tags: forms, ajax

Hi I'm a newbie to drupal and I'm practicing using drupal 7 forms #ajax.

I have 2 fieldsets the ingredient fieldset and the steps fieldset.

when I click add step it works fine but when I click add ingredient and remove a step from the step fieldset  the step fieldset turns into ingredient field set

[image]

here's my form and functions

```
function recipe_new_recipe($form, &$form_state) {
$form = array();

$form['#tree'] = TRUE;

// Fieldset for details of recipe
$form['details_fieldset'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Recipe Details'),
);

$form['details_fieldset']['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Recipe name'),
    '#description' => t('Name of the recipe'),
);

$form['details_fieldset']['description'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Description'),
    '#description' => t('Recipe description'),
    '#resizable' => FALSE,
);

$form['details_fieldset']['time'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 10,
    '#title' => t('Preparation time'),
    '#description' => t('Recipe preparation time'),
);

$form['details_fieldset']['serving_size'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 8,
    '#title' => t('Serving size'),
    '#description' => t('Recipe serving size'),
);

// Initialization of variables for ingredients
if(empty($form_state['ingredient_num'])) {
    // ingredient number f
    $form_state['ingredient_num'] = 1;
    // ingredient checker array stores all removed  ingredients
    $form_state['ingredient_check'] = array ();
    $form_state['ingredient_count'] = 1;
    $form_state['ingredient_check'][$form_state['ingredient_num']] = 1;
}
// Fieldset for ingredients
$form['ingredient_fieldset'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Recipe ingredients'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="recipe_ingredients">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',

);
//For loop for dynamic fields for ingredients
for ($i=1; $i <= $form_state['ingredient_num']; $i++) {
    // check array = 1 render the field ( for rendering field in the bottom only )
    if($form_state['ingredient_check'][$i] == 1){
        $form['ingredient_fieldset']['ingredient'][$i]['field'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#prefix' => '<div id = "ingredient_'. $i . '">',
        );

        if ($form_state['ingredient_count'] != 1) {
            $form['ingredient_fieldset']['ingredient'][$i]['remove_ingredient'] = array(
              '#type' => 'submit',
              '#value' => t('Remove'),
              '#submit' => array('remove_ingredient_list'), // function submit callback for removing ingredients
              '#suffix' => '</div>',
              '#name' => $i,
              '#ajax' => array(
                'callback' => 'ajax_remove_ingredient', // ajax callback function for removing ingredients
                'wrapper' => 'recipe_ingredients',
              ),
            );
        }
    }

}
// Add new ingredients button 
$form['ingredient_fieldset']['add_ingredient'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('add another ingredient'),
    '#submit' => array('add_ingredient_list'), // function submit callback for adding ingredients
            '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'ajax_add_ingredient', // ajax callback function for adding ingredients
        'wrapper' => 'recipe_ingredients'
    ),
);
// Fieldset steps
$form['step_fieldset'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Recipe steps'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="recipe_steps">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',

);
// Step variables initialization
if(empty($form_state['step_num'])) {
    $form_state['step_num'] = 1;
    $form_state['step_check'] = array ();
    $form_state['step_count'] = 1;
    $form_state['step_check'][$form_state['step_num']] = 1;
}
//For loop for dynamic fields for steps
for ($j=1 ; $j <= $form_state['step_num']; $j++) { 

    if($form_state['step_check'][$j] == 1){
        // check array = 1 render the field ( for rendering field in the bottom only )
        $form['step_fieldset']['step'][$j]['field'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#prefix' => '<div id = "step'. $j . '">',
        );


        if($form_state['step_count'] != 1){
            $form['step_fieldset']['step'][$j]['remove_step'] = array(
              '#type' => 'submit',
              '#value' => t('Remove'),
              '#submit' => array('remove_step_list'), // function submit callback for removing steps
              '#suffix' => '</div>',
              '#name' => $j,
              '#ajax' => array(
                'callback' => 'remove_step', // ajax callback function for removing steps
                'wrapper' => 'recipe_steps' ,
              ),
            );
        }
    }

}
// Add new steps button 
$form['step_fieldset']['add_step'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('add another step'),
    '#submit' => array('add_step_list'),
            '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'add_step',
        'wrapper' => 'recipe_steps',
    ),
);

$form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit recipe'),
);

return $form; 
}

function add_ingredient_list($form, &$form_state){
$form_state['ingredient_num']++;
$check = $form_state['ingredient_num'];
$form_state['ingredient_count']++;
$form_state['ingredient_check'][$check] = 1;
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function remove_ingredient_list($form, &$form_state) {
$key = $form_state['triggering_element']['#name'];
$form_state['ingredient_count']--;
$form_state['ingredient_check'][$key] = 2;
$form['ingredient_fieldset']['ingredient'][$key]['field']['#access'] =    FALSE;
$form['ingredient_fieldset']['ingredient'][$key]['remove_name']['#access'] = FALSE;
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
function ajax_add_ingredient($form, $form_state) {
return $form['ingredient_fieldset'];
}
function ajax_remove_ingredient($form, $form_state) {
return $form['ingredient_fieldset'];
}
function add_step_list($form, &$form_state){
$form_state['step_num']++;
$check = $form_state['step_num'];
$form_state['step_count']++;
$form_state['step_check'][$check] = 1;
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
function remove_step_list($form, &$form_state) {
$key = $form_state['triggering_element']['#name'];
$form_state['step_count']--;
$form_state['step_check'][$key] = 2;
$form['step_fieldset']['step'][$key]['field']['#access'] = FALSE;
$form['step_fieldset']['step'][$key]['remove_name']['#access'] = FALSE;
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
function add_step($form, $form_state) {
return $form['step_fieldset'];
}
function remove_step($form, $form_state) {
return $form['step_fieldset'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently, as it turns out it was calling the wrong callback because you need to have a unique '#name' for each of the buttons.

In your code you have the '#name' as $i and $j which represents a number but this means that the '#name' is not unique as both $i and $j can have the same number.

So for example, this:

```
'#name' => $i,
```

Should be something like:

```
'#name' => 'remove_ingredient_' . $i,
```

This differentiates the two so the right callback is used.

You then need to strip the text out of the '#name' to use the key:

```
function remove_ingredient_list($form, &$form_state) {
  $key = $form_state['triggering_element']['#name'];
  $key = str_replace('remove_ingredient_', '', $key);
  $form_state['ingredient_count']--;
  $form_state['ingredient_check'][$key] = 2;
```

I realise this is an old question but hopefully it helps anyone else having the same issue :-)